# C# compiler error CS1061 by generic Method

Tags: c#, generics

I have an generic List-Class and I want to use my Method CorrectData() from this class.
At the moment I have implementated the Method CorrectData() into the class LoadListe. If I put this into the generic List then I get an compiler error CS1061.

Whats wrong?

Thanks
Steffen

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WindowsFormsGenerics
{
    /// <summary>Basisklasse für alle Elemente </summary>
    public class Base
    {
        /// <summary> Elementname </summary>
        public string Name { get; set; }

        /// <summary> Beschreibung </summary>
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
    public class Knoten : Base { }
    public class OneNodeElement : Base
    {
        /// <summary> KnotenOne des Elementes </summary>
        public Knoten KnotenOne { get; set; }
        /// <summary> Schaltzustand am KnotenOne </summary>
        public bool SwitchOne { get; set; }
    }
    public class Load : OneNodeElement
    {
        public void CorrectData(){}
    }
    public sealed class LoadListe : Liste<Load>
    {
        public void CorrectData()
        {
            foreach (Load item in this)
            {
                item.CorrectData();
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract class Liste<T> : Collection<T> where T : Base
    {
        public T GetItem(string searchsString, string parameter = "NAME")
        {
            return null;
        }

        public void CorrectData()
        {
            foreach (T item in this)
            {
                item.CorrectData();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it too hard to give also the error message? And indicate on which line you got the error. You are wasting our time by hiding us information you already know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `CorrectData` implementation or at least definition inside `Base` class. You could define your `Base` class like this:

```
public class Base
{
    /// <summary> Elementname </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary> Beschreibung </summary>
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual void CorrectData() { }
}
```

And then override `CorrectData` method in descendants, like this:

```
public class Load : OneNodeElement
{
    public override void CorrectData() { }
}
```

Comment: I would use this method. Tanks Steffen

Answer (score 1):

You define `where T : Base` and then want to call `CorrectData()` on an item of that type. Such a method is not implemented in the `Base` class.

That method is implemented in the `Load` class, so you could use `where T: Load` instead or add the `CorrectData()` method in the `Base` class.