# Error CS1061 - List<T>.Item[Int32] Property

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, generic-list

This problem is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178151/does-not-contain-a-definition-and-no-extension-method-error), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502287/does-not-contain-a-definition-and-no-extension-method-error), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706594/system-web-httppostedfilebase-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-hasfile-and) (same error, different source class), and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39337510/c-sharp-compiler-error-cs1061-by-generic-method) (same error, different reason).

After compiling my programs in a project to check for errors, I got the following **CS1061** error:

> Entity.cs(291,24): error CS1061: '`List<Entity>`' does not contain a 
>   definition for 'Item' and no extension method 'Item' accepting a first 
>   argument of type '`List<Entity>`' could be found (are you missing a 
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Entity.cs** is the name of the file where the error occurred, and said error occurs in the **Load()** function, shown below:

```
public void Load(){
    /*
        Try to spawn the entity.
        If there are too many entities
        on-screen, unload any special
        effect entities.
        If that fails, produce an error message
    */
    try{
        if(EntitiesArray.Count >= EntitiesOnScreenCap){
            if(this.Type == EntityType.SpecialEffect)
                Unload();
            else
                throw null;
        }else
            //Place the entity in the first available slot in the array
            for(int i = 0; i < EntitiesArray.Capacity; i++)
                if(EntitiesArray.Item[i] == NullEntity)
                    EntitiesArray.Item[i] = this;
    }catch(Exception exc){
        throw new LoadException("Failed to load entity.");
    }
}
```

The error happens on these lines (lines 291 & 292):

```
if(EntitiesArray.Item[i] == NullEntity)
    EntitiesArray.Item[i] = this;
```

`NullEntity` is a field of type `Entity`, and `this` is also of type `Entity`.

`EntitesArray` is a `List<Entity>` and, therefore, should have an `Item[]` property, according to the MSDN documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx).
`Entity` does not have a method or array named `Item`.

Declaration at beginning of class `Entity`:

```
public static List<Entity> EntitiesArray;
```

Instantiation in a method in `Entity` that is guaranteed to run only once:

```
EntitiesArray = new List<Entity>(EntitiesOnScreenCap);
```

Field `EntitiesOnScreenCap` is an `int` equal to 200.

This is included at the highest scope (before the *namespace*), so there should not be any problems regarding this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

---

What is causing this **CS1061** error, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Item` property isn't a normal property in C#. It is a way to indicate that you can use an indexer to reference a specific item from the Enumerable. To use it, you just put the indexer value inside square brackets:

```
EntitiesArray[i]
```

Comment: Oh, so it's like using a regular array in that respect.

Comment: The syntax is the same, and in the case of a List, yes, it basically works the same way. However, it's possible to have non-integer indexers, and they can even be overloaded. For example, a `NameValueCollection` has both an int and a string indexer. So you can reference an item either by position or name. For example, both `nvc[0]` and `nvc["FirstName"]` are valid for a `NameValueCollection` named `nvc`.